# Shell Script For Loop Exits After Finishing First Loop

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

Code works fine until the last for loop.
It tries to login database. Either, it establish a successful connection with database or not, script gives output OK/NOT OK depending to the connection and then exit the shell script. What should I do to solve this?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Username: ' var_username
read -sp 'Password: ' var_password

filename="$1"

while read -r line; do
name=$(sed 's/#.*$//g; s/(.*$//g; s/=.*$//g; s/).*$//g')
done < "$filename"

#retval=$? | tail -n1|grep OK

for tns in $name
do
tnsping $tns
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
echo $tns 'tnsping i calismiyor' >>tnslatest.log
else
echo $tns 'tnsping i calisiyor' >>tnslatest.log
working_tns+=($tns)
fi
done


#The following lines do not work properly.#
for working in $working_tns
do
echo "exit" | sqlplus -L $var_username/$var_password@$working | grep             
Connected > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
    echo "OK"
 else
    echo "NOT OK"
 fi
done
```

For example; my tnsnames.ora file contains 4 tns.
So, I want to have for output like OK or NOT OK in total.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you wanted to iterate thru an array you probably need `"${working_tns[@]}"` in the last for-loop

Comment: That first `while read` loop isn't doing what you think it is. I'm not sure what you think it's doing, but it's doing something nonsensical.

Comment: Have you tried [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net)?